# Two blocks of text side by side, truncate and add ellipsis to one block if necessary

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a table with % cell width. The table is a NgGrid in AngularJS (based on divs).

There is a text (or link) in this cell of various length. And a few badges with float left.

In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fp53kyo) example 3 cases:

1. Expected behavior with a short text in cell (would like to notice that text should fill all free space)
2. Problem with a long text. Text should be truncated with ellipsis and badge should be visible
3. Expected rendering for a long text. If you'll try to resize canvas you'll see the problem of this approach (breakline)

Code:

```
<p>1. Expected behavior with a short text</p>
<div class="container">
    <span class="text">short text</span>
    <span class="label">label</span>
</div>


<p>2. Problem with a long text</p>
<div class="container">
    <span class="text">long textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong text</span>
    <span class="label"></span>
</div>

<p>3. Expected result with a long text</p>
<div class="container">
    <span class="text example">long textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong text</span>
    <span class="label example">label</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The `text example` class works perfectly, isn't it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Try to resize canvas.

Comment: You mean to say that even the third example has a problem when screen is very narrow e.g. 300px? Is is possible to set a fixed width on `.label` instead of percent?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But there can be 2 badges with a fixed width. And how to set % width on text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is possible to re-arrange the order of label and text then the following CSS rules should do the trick:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="label">label</span>
    <span class="text">some very long text</span>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    /* nothing */
}
.label {
    float: right;
}
.text {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/9fp53kyo/3/)